# Submit a Form without Reloading

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I got this simple form page that will submit the last name and first name of a user

```
<?php
include 'dbconnect.php';

if (isset($_POST['lname']) && isset($_POST['fname'])){
$ln = $_POST['lname'];
$fn = $_POST['fname'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO user_tbl (`lastname`,`firstname`) VALUES ('$ln','$fn')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
}
?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
    <script >var frm = $('#nameFrm');
            frm.submit(function (ev) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: frm.attr('method'),
                    url: frm.attr('action'),
                    data: frm.serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert('ok');
                    }
                });

                ev.preventDefault();
            });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id = "nameFrm" name = "frmName" method = "POST" >
        Last Name : <input type = "text" name = "lname"><br />
        First Name: <input type = "text" name = "fname"><br />
        <input type = "submit" value = "submit" name= "subbtn"  >
    </form>
</body>
```

my script does not work that script is suppose to avoid the page from reloading and i am pretty sure that it is reloading everytime the page is submitted

also when i seperate the php code

```
if (isset($_POST['lname']) && isset($_POST['fname'])){
$ln = $_POST['lname'];
$fn = $_POST['fname'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_tbl (`lastname`,`firstname`) VALUES ('$ln','$fn')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
}
```

it still redirects it to the new php file

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What to do is create a new file called **requests.php** / or whatever

in this file have a switch statement..

**requests.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['action']) && ($_POST['action']!='')){

   $action = $_POST['action'];
   switch($action){
     case "submitForm" :
         include 'dbconnect.php';
         if ( (isset($_POST['lname'])) && (isset($_POST['fname'])) ){
           $ln = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lname']);
           $fn = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
           $sql = "INSERT INTO user_tbl (`lastname`,`firstname`) VALUES ('$ln','$fn')";
           mysql_query($sql);
           echo "New values updated: ".$fn." ".$ln;
        }
     break;
   }

}
?>
```

Then copy this crude html..

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 

    jQuery("#nameFrm").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var frm = jQuery('#nameFrm');
        var outPut = jQuery('#results');
        var loadImg = jQuery('#loadingImage');

        var fname = jQuery('#fname').val();
        var lname = jQuery('#lname').val();

        jQuery.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
               data:'action=submitForm&fname='+fname+'&lname='+lname,
               url: 'requests.php',
               beforeSend: function(){ 
                loadImg.show(); 
               },
               complete: function(){ 
                loadImg.hide();
               },
            success: function(data) { 
                frm.hide();
                outPut.html(data);
           }
           });
    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="requests.php" id="nameFrm" name="frmName" method="POST" >
        Last Name : <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br />
        First Name: <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br />
        <input type = "submit" value = "submit" name= "subbtn"  >
    </form>
    <div id="loadingImage" style="display:none; text-align:center;">
        <img src="http://craigmaslowski.com/images/activity-indicator.gif" />
    </div>
    <div id="results"></div>
</body>
```

What its doing is when you click the submit button, the jquery will fire, 
it will grab the 2 values from fname & lname (these have been given an id)
the 2 values will then be added to the jquery.ajax URL, this url will be the form action url, which for this is requests.php

in requests.php the 2 post values are passed over and processed, the output will be sent back to the original page, were the data will be passed to the div#results, to show the output....

Also I've added a few other things, like a loading image, for both the beforeSend call and Complete,

**ALSO, 
please be-aware that you should really think about moving from using the mysql_query syntax to mysqli_query.. have a look at MackieeE's comment!
**

Have a play around with it.. hopefully its what your looking for..
Good luck..

Marty

Comment: I did this and it sended undefined to both firstname and lastname although it did stay on the same page will see what is making it undefined

Comment: SUperb,,, also using the likes of chromes developer tools you can see the xjax requests being made, whats being passed and where its passing it to, along with the return data, or if firefox, use firebug to have a look :)

Comment: good tip about the dev tool its good to find out about that thx

Comment: Can I ask you some more so I relay the same method to my chat box it no longer is reloading but I am getting this value [object HTMLInputElement] instead of the chat content

Comment: man NVM that question (I figured it out )I love you from the bottom of *that part of the brain :3* You don't know how much i needed this

Answer (score 0):

The browser executes the javascript BEFORE knowing the form.
Put the javascript AFTER the form or into a $(window).load():

```
<script>
    $( window ).load(function() {

        var frm = $('#nameFrm');
        frm.submit(function (ev) {
            $.ajax({
                type: frm.attr('method'),
                url: frm.attr('action'),
                data: frm.serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('ok');
                }
            });

            ev.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```